# How do I allow a browser on IOS 13 to access my iPhone 6s' Gyroscope?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, safari, aframe, google-cardboard

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161856/how-do-i-allow-glitch-com-to-access-my-gyroscope-and-use-it-for-cardboard-vr)

I am attempting to run a webVR program using A-Frame on my iPhone 6s, and these three browsers I have tested do not have access to my gyroscope.

```
Safari
Chrome
Firefox
```

I believe this could be fixed if the apps had the permission to, but there is not an easy way to do this switch that I have found. If anyone can give me a way to do this (without jailbreaking) it would be appreciated.

Currently when I enter https://vrfinal.glitch.me and switch to google cardboard view on chrome, it bugs out and does not roatate my view when my phone moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [A-Frame master build](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@333873f3279c8d49881577662e16e51baa480ea3/dist/aframe-master.min.js) on iOS 13+. Make sure to serve your content over https.

Corrected [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sleet-violin?path=index.html:6:0). Make sure you [access over HTTPS](https://sleet-violin.glitch.me/)

Comment: I am confused, should I add this as a script to my VR program? Could you just specify what exactly to add?

Comment: Updated answer to include corrected glitch. You have to point the script tag to the aframe build I pointed out `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@333873f3279c8d49881577662e16e51baa480ea3/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>`