# Gyroscope problem with 360° Panorama on phone

Tags: aframe

I all,
I've installed the aFrame examples on my web site but I encouter a problem with the 360 Panorama with my phone. The Gyroscopic functions doasn't work.
The image is blocked and I can only move it with the finger on the screen. It doesn't move with my head.
Do I miss something ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I allow a browser on IOS 13 to access my iPhone 6s' Gyroscope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59183207/how-do-i-allow-a-browser-on-ios-13-to-access-my-iphone-6s-gyroscope)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184638/12282360) is the answer to a very similar question I asked. You are probably using the wrong build of AFRAME for your ios